# Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: ionic-framework

I am trying to set the value of the attendance.studentName using value on ion-input. But I am getting an error.

I want to push the value of the ion-input and ion-select to firebase.

```
  <!-- When I delete the ngModel it works -->
  <ion-input disabled="true" value="{{student.name}}" [(ngModel)]="attendance.studentName" > {{student.name}} </ion-input>

  <ion-select item-end [ngModel]="attendance.status">
    <ion-option value="Present">Present</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="Absent">Absent</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="Late">Late</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

**EDIT **

I am fetching the value of the input from firebase and i dont want the user to edit it so I disabled it. Then i fetch the input using the ngModel.

Here's my code..

> TS

```
import { Student } from '../../models/students/students.model';
import { Attendance } from '../../models/attendance/attendance.model';


export class CheckAttendancePage {

  studentList$: Observable<Student[]>

  attendance: Attendance = {
    studentName: '',
    status: ''
  }

  constructor(private afDatabase: AngularFireDatabase, private studentsList: StudentListService, private attendanceList: AttendanceListService,
  public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    this.studentList$ = this.studentsList
      .getStudentList()
      .snapshotChanges()
      .map(
        changes => {
          return changes.map(c => ({
          key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val()
          }))
        }
      )
  }

addAttendance(attendance: Attendance){
    console.log(attendance)
}
```

> HTML

Comment: are you solve this.... if not then comment me @Mj Isip

Comment: I am still working on it

Comment: Can you help me? @Utpaul

Comment: your purpose please ... you want to two way binding attendance.status and attendance.studentName? and you need to show in console...

Comment: check my answer

Comment: It goes like this. I'm fetching the value of the input from Firebase database. That will be the permanent value of the input as I dont want the user to edit the input. @Utpaul

Comment: now check my answer @Mj Isip

Comment: where student object

Comment: check my reply sir @Utpaul

Comment: @Utpaul sir????

Comment: now check @MJIsip

Answer (score 0):

**In `.ts` file need to setup `attendance` object**

```
attendance:any={'studentName': '', .'status':''}
```

**in constructor you can set this value**

```
this.attendance.studentName = your firbase name
```

**In `.html` file**

```
<ion-item>

  <ion-input disabled="true" [(ngModel)]="attendance.studentName" type="text">
  </ion-input>

  <ion-select item-end [(ngModel)]="attendance.status">
    <ion-option value="Present">Present</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="Absent">Absent</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="Late">Late</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

**Setting value of `attendance.studentName` in constructor**

```
constructor(private firebaseDB: AngularFireDatabase){

  this.firabase= this.firebaseDB.list('/users');// your route
  this.attendance.studentName= this.firabase.name;
}
```

**Setting value of `attendance.studentName` in user define method suppose its name `Dbcall`**

First of all inject `public navCtrl: NavController` in `constructor`

```
Dbcall(){
  this.attendance.studentName= database student value
  this.navCtrl.setRoot(this.navCtrl.getActive().component);
}
```

Comment: cannot find the "student" on student.name

Comment: what do you mean by your firebase name on line.. 
    this.attendance.studentName = your firbase name

Sorry, I'm completed new to Ionic, please bear with me

Comment: Wow. I worked. The "Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError" is gone but how can I set the value of the attendance.studentName if it comes from the database?

Comment: are you solve basis of my answer then must be give right tik mark....... 
So attendance.studentName = student.name

Comment: Sorry sir? I cant understand what your saying

Comment: if its came from database then set the value to attendance.studentName .. if this process work on constructor then no need to refresh page otherwise need to refresh active page

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: constructor, how?

Comment: Wait. I'll try to find answers on how to get the database student value

Comment: Or can you just tell me how? Please?

Comment: I store the data on firebase database